# Inner join equivalent of this subquery?

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery

I have these tables

`BooksCatalog`
`[BookCatalogID],[BooksCatalogBookID],[ReceivedFrom],[BillNo],[billdate]`

`Books`
`[BookID],[BookTitle],[ISBN],[ISBN13],[BookAuthorID],[BookPublisherID],[YearPublished],[NumberOfPages],[Volume],[edition],[Price]`

`Authors`
`[AuthorID],[AuthorName],[AuthorCityID],[AuthorStateID],[PhoneNumber],[Email],[Website]`

I am running this query,

```
SELECT Books.BookTitle FROM Books 
        INNER JOIN Authors ON Authors.AuthorId=Books.BookAuthorID
        WHERE Books.BookID IN 
        (SELECT BooksCatalog.BooksCatalogBookID FROM BooksCatalog
        WHERE BooksCatalog.billdate = (SELECT MIN(BooksCatalog.billdate) FROM BooksCatalog))
        AND
        AUTHORS.AuthorName = @AuthorName;
```

as it is using 2 subqueries, I am getting a feeling that its not optimized, and it could perform better if used with equivalent inner join. So, what's the equivalent inner join for this? What I am doing is find the first of of given author that was added to the library.

Comment: Modern RDBMS usually optimize queries, so I wouldn't worry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot to be said for using aliases, the schema prefix, and naming an element (such as a BookId or AuthorId) the same thing throughout the schema. Does it really need to be called a BookAuthorId or a BooksCatalogBookID?

Anyway your query can be re-written a little tidier this way, but as @billy suggested, it probably won't really benefit from a vastly different plan:

```
SELECT b.BookTitle 
FROM dbo.Books AS b 
INNER JOIN Authors AS a 
ON a.AuthorId = b.BookAuthorID
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT BookId = MIN(BooksCatalogBookID)
   FROM dbo.BooksCatalog 
) AS bc
ON bc.BookId = b.BookId
WHERE a.AuthorName = @AuthorName;
```

Seems though that you're relying on a very peculiar join criteria here. What are the odds that out of all the books in the catalog, the one with the earliest bill date will also happen to be written by the one author you've identified? Is it possible your logic really meant to be to get the first billed book from the specified author? If so then maybe this makes more sense:

```
;WITH x(BookTitle, rn) AS
(
  SELECT b.BookTitle, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bc.billdate)
    FROM dbo.BooksCatalog AS bc
    INNER JOIN b.Books AS b
    ON b.BookId = bc.BooksCatalogBookID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Authors AS a
    ON b.BookAuthorID = a.AuthorID
    WHERE a.AuthorName = @AuthorName
)
SELECT BookTitle FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: @AaronBertand:
yes, that's exactly what I am asking! I need the first billed book for the given author. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace one subquery with inner join.

```
            SELECT Books.BookTitle 
              FROM Books 
        INNER JOIN Authors 
                ON Authors.AuthorId = Books.BookAuthorID
        INNER JOIN BooksCatalog 
                ON BooksCatalog.BooksCatalogBookID = Books.BookID 
               AND BooksCatalog.billdate = (SELECT MIN(BooksCatalog.billdate) FROM BooksCatalog) WHERE BooksCatalogBookID = Books.BookID)
        WHERE      Authors.AuthorName = @AuthorName;
```